# predict.mmer function in sommer package

Tags: r, prediction, mixed-models

I run a model for multi environment analysis using the "mmer" function of the sommer package, but when I try to get the blups for random effects the following issue is shown:

```
predict.mmer(object = mix, classify = "Local")
```

fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 5 columns / coefficients
iteration    LogLik     wall    cpu(sec)   restrained
1      -175.248   18:50:45      2           1
2      -175.248   18:50:47      4           1
3      -175.248   18:50:48      5           1
4      -175.248   18:50:50      7           1
fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 5 columns / coefficients
Error in modelForMatrices$Beta[unlist(betas0[fToUse]), 1] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In x[...] <- m :number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

The model I adjusted in Sommer package was:
mix<-mmer(Peso~Local:Test + Local,  random = ~vs(us(Local),Genotipo) + Local:Bloco,  rcov = ~units, data = dados, tolparinv = 0.7)

I have three environments (Local) About 250 genotypes tested in each environment (Genotipo) Four blocks in each environment (Bloco) About 20 check treatments repeated in all environments (Test) The response variable is cassava root yield (Peso)

As I do not see the dimensions of the matrices/tables used inside the function, which resource to use in order to get the predictions?

Best
Helcio

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to recreate your error, then we can provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The predict function has been a headache for years for the mmer() function but now is working well in the mmec implementation. Please try the mmec() function with something like this:

```
library(sommer)
data(DT_example)
DT <- DT_example
A <- A_example
head(DT)
length(unique(DT$Env))
DT=DT[with(DT, order(Env)), ]
ans2us <- mmec(Yield~Env,
             random= ~ vsc(usc(Env),isc(Name)),
             rcov= ~ vsc(dsc(Env),isc(units)),
             data=DT)
plot(ans2us$llik[1,])
summary(ans2us)$varcomp
pp <- predict(ans2us, D="Name")
pp$pvals
lattice::levelplot(cov2cor(ans2us$theta[[1]]))
```

In addition, unstructured models tend to have convergence issues and singularities due to the many covariance parameters, and the high likelihood of getting non-full-rank covariance matrices during the REML process. You may want to try reduced-rank factor analytic models to guarantee the convergence and increase speed.

```
# less accurate but is guaranteed to converge
M <- with(DT, rrc(Env, Name, Yield, nPC=2))
ans2fa <- mmec(Yield~Env,
              random= ~ vsc(usc( M ),isc(Name)),
              rcov= ~ vsc(dsc(Env),isc(units)),
              nIters = 100,
              data=DT)
summary(ans2fa)$varcomp
plot(ans2fa$llik[1,])
ppfa <- predict(ans2fa, D="Name")
ppfa$pvals

Lam <- with(DT, rrc(Env, Name, Yield, nPC=2, returnLam = TRUE))$Lam
scores <- ans2fa$uList[[1]]
BLUP <- scores %*% t(Lam)
lattice::levelplot(cor(BLUP))

# highly correlated predictions
plot(pp$pvals$predicted.value, ppfa$pvals$predicted.value)
```

Cheers